# On MAC OS machine. How can we convert date in 2017-01-09T09:35:26Z to Timestamp using shell script

Tags: macos, shell, timestamp

I tried some conversion methods but failed. I couldn't interpret the input date format correctly.

Below is the command i used to convert

`date -j -u -f "%a %b %d %T %Z %Y" "Tue Sep 28 19:35:15 EDT 2010" "+%s"`

And i am looking for a command that works for every Time Zone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, **what a hassle** for such a simple question. (PS: I think it was downvoted for not showing an error message, and the use of the OSX tag might better be replaced for macOS if you are on an up-to-date Mac).

The first problem I found out by reading [this](https://blog.frd.mn/puzzling-with-os-xs-date/) post. It explains that in order for your command to work the abbreviations need to be in the system language. This can be solved by adding `LANG=C` in front of your command.

However, your command still delivered the following error:

```
Failed conversion of ``Tue Sep 28 19:35:15 EDT 2010'' using format ``%a %b %d %T %Z %Y''
date: illegal time format
usage: date [-jnRu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ... 
            [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]
```

Then, when looking into `man date` I found this line explaining the -f argument:

> **-f**    Use input_fmt as the format string to parse the new_date provided rather than using the default
>                [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss] format.  Parsing is done using **strptime(3)**.

Then, in `man strptime` I read:

> **Bugs** - The %Z format specifier only accepts time zone abbreviations of
>   the local
>        time zone, or the value "GMT".  This limitation is because of ambiguity
>        due to of the over loading of time zone abbreviations.  One such example
>        is EST which is both Eastern Standard Time and Eastern Australia Summer
>        Time.

So, I was able to execute your command either like so:

`LANG=C date -j -u -f '%a %b %d %T %Z %Y' 'Tue Sep 28 19:35:15 GMT 2010' +%s`

Or, like so,

`TZ=EDT LANG=C date -j -u -f '%a %b %d %T %Z %Y' 'Tue Sep 28 19:35:15 GMT 2010' +%s`

But both aren't actually what you where looking for I guess..

You thus seem to be bitten by a known bug in the default macOS version of strptime.

**EDIT**

However, if you would have a list with the offset of each timezone (the offset towards GMT), you could do something like:

`TZ=EDT LANG=C date -juf '%a %b %d %T %z %Y' 'Tue Sep 28 19:35:15 -0400 2010' +%s`

Have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7343378/4041795) for more possibilities.